# Reading multiple CSV files with headers in python with numpy?

Tags: python

Currently I am using this code to read one complete csv file to my code:

```
data = np.loadtxt('csv_Complete.csv', delimiter=',', skiprows=1)
```

However, Now I have multiple csv files that are in this format.

Log1.csv

```
x1,x2,x3,x4....
1.5,3,5,7,8
2,5,1.2,5,2
1,3,3,5.5,6
```

log2.csv

```
 x1,x2,x3,x4....
 1,3.3,5,7,8
 2,5.1,1,5.5,2
 1,3,3,5,6
```

This is the method I am thinking of doing but it is not working. Getting a 
ValueError: could not convert string to float:

```
log1 = np.loadtxt('log1.csv', delimiter=',', skiprows=1)
log2 = np.loadtxt('log2.csv', delimiter=',', skiprows=1)
log3 = np.loadtxt('log3.csv', delimiter=',', skiprows=1)
data = np.append([log1, log2, log3])
```

The error I am getting is:

```
 File "<ipython-input-6-6155c8de61ad>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Mmyname/.spyder2-py3/setdataexp.py', wdir='C:/Users/myname/.spyder2-py3')

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 714, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 89, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/myname/.spyder2-py3/setdataexp.py", line 5, in <module>
    log1 = np.loadtxt('log40a.csv', delimiter=',', skiprows=1)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 930, in loadtxt
    items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 930, in <listcomp>
    items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 659, in floatconv
    return float(x)

ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Comment: Both of your example files load fine for me. Are you sure all three input files have only a single line of header, and all the rest is a proper csv until the end? I doubt it. Also, check where the error is coming from: it should be one of the `loadtxt` calls, telling you which file is problematic.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I edited the question with the error.

Comment: It might be an issue with a blank line at the end of your file... just a guess.

Comment: Are you *sure* you didn't miss a few final lines of the traceback...? Anyway, look at `log40a.csv`. That's the problematic one.

Comment: @AndrasDeak No that is all in the traceback. I just tried switching it so it reads the log40b first and I get the same error with log40b being the problem.

Comment: @AndrasDeak If that data contained a hex number does it automatically converts it? I just realized one of my column is in hex format of 0x0001

Comment: @J.Jones are those hex values only present in the problematic file? You know how it goes: put together a small dummy file that looks like your real one (we could even call it a [mcve]), and try if your reader breaks on it. If it doesn't then your data is corrupt somewhere: some of those values is not what you think it is.

Comment: Can you view the file within Notepad++?  I've found that to be very helpful for seeing what is REALLY contained in different CSV files.  Sometimes files contain special characters that you can't 'see' in the CSV itself.

Answer (score 1):

It must be a `missing value` in file  `log40a.csv`.

I have the same error for file like:

```
x1,x2,x3,x4....
1,3.3,5,7,8
2,5.1,,5.5,2
1,3,3,5,6
```

Base on [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) if you have missing values you should use [genfromtxt function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html#numpy.genfromtxt).

Comment: Yes I do have some missing values. Is it possible to have it skip it?

Comment: Actually, I would rather it uses the last value in the same row as the missing value is that possible?

Comment: You can find all missing values, replace them with last in row and than use  `loadtxt` function. You need to prepare your data files at first.

Comment: @J.Jones I think you could set a signalling value as a default for missing data points, then later find those and replace with the relevant last element of each row. I don't think you need other preprocessing for this.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I looked at the data again. There is no missing values. There is a gap in time but that doesn't translate to missing values in the columns or rows. So rows and columns are filled with something. That brings me back to square 1.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I think what is happening is that append is returning a string and not a float. Could that be it?

Comment: @J.Jones no, your error clearly comes from the reading phase, append will never return a string for you.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I see, ok I tried genfromtxt and now I get this error data = np.append([log1, log2])

TypeError: append() missing 1 required positional argument: 'values', the error message didn't really turn anything up on google.

Comment: @J.Jones You call `append` function in wrong way. [Here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) you find more information.

Comment: @torm I tried this way: data = np.genfromtxt('log40a.csv', dtype = float, delimiter=',', skip_header =1)
log2 = np.genfromtxt('log40b.csv', delimiter=',', skip_header= 1)
np.append([data], [log2]) , however, it only plots the first set of data in log40a.

Comment: Which variable do you plot? I guess that you plot `data`. You should do this: `c = np.append([data], [log2])` than `plot(c)`